# SQL Casting Date vs DateTime

Tags: postgresql, datetime

When I write SQL scripts to find a date range using a DateTime field, such as between '01/01/2018' and '07/31/2018', I always do something like this:

```
   start_date >='2018-01-01' and end_date < '2018-08-01'
```

I do this in order to capture all the records from 07/31/2018 because of the timestamp from the DateTime datatype.

I'm working at a new place that uses PostGresql and I've noticed that they cast all the DateTime fields first:

```
    '2018-07-31'::date end_date
```

They then write all their date ranges like this:

```
    start_date >='2018-01-01' and end_date <='2018-07-31'
```

Does casting the DateTime field to a Date return an accurate result this way? 
 I'm having trouble testing this because everything here runs so slow and I'm just now learning how the system works.

Comment: I like your way better. Seems expensive to cast every record just to do a comparison. That being said if they are just casting string literals to dates `'2018-07-31'::date end_date` then it's a wash.

Comment: But will the casting of the DateTime to a Date give the desired output of including the entire day of '2018-07-31'?

Comment: Firstly please be precise, there's no such thing as a "DateTime" type in postgres, and the code `'2018-07-31'::date end_date` doesn't seem to make sense - are you trying to say they're casting the table field to `date`, as opposed to casting a literal string to `date`? If that's the case, it's definitely a bad idea to cast the field value, as that will prevent it using that field's index (assuming a standard index). Assuming the field type is `timestamp` and you want to get values between 2018-01-01 and 2018-0731 (inc), do: `field BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31 23:59:59'`, or similar.

Comment: Casting a timestamp to date will essentially truncate the time component of the field for the comparison (which is an expensive operation and would cause an index to be avoided as @eurotrash mentions) If the fields are timestamp and they are doin `start_date::date >= '2018-01-01' AND end_date::date <= '2018-07-31'` then they should reconsider. Besides the BETWEEN option shared in eurotrashes comment, you could also do `start_date >='2018-01-01 00:00:00' and end_date < '2018-08-01 00:00:00'` I would avoid putting a date literal in there to avoid an accidental implicit cast of the field.

Comment: @eurotrash--I meant "timestamp."  I'm still used to SQL Server